# Ember - How do you preselect items in multiselect when using hasMany attribute?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am currently having issues preselecting items in the multiselect view. I'm using ember 1.3 with ember-data 1.0.0 beta 6 and ember-data-django-rest-adapter.

```
App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  authors: hasMany('author')
});

App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('article', params.article_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});

App.ArticleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['authors'],
  allAuthors: function() {
    return this.store.find('author');
  }.property()
});
```

Template:

```
{{input authors as='select'
  multiple='true'
  collection='allAuthors'
  selection='authors'
  optionValuePath='content.id'
  optionLabelPath='content.name'}}
```

I'm not sure why this is not working because when I output **allAuthors** and **authors** using *#each* in the template, I'm getting the data that I should.

Is there something I'm missing to do?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the Ember.Select view? It seems to be geared more towards what you want. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

Comment: I switched to view Ember.Select but it's behaving the same way. Thanks for giving me another thing to try though.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue you're having? The input is selecting the correct items?

Comment: It's not pre-selecting the items I want it to select.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prepopulate this kind of data in the route using a promise:

```
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('article', params.article_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.store.find('author').then(function(authors) {
      controller.set('allAuthors', authors);
      // or maybe controller.get('allAuthors').addObjects(authors);
    });
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});

App.ArticleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['authors'],
  allAuthors: []
});
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it's what worked for me.